# Window defender wants to reset your setting" -ChromeDriver 2.29 issue:ChromeBrowser opening with a new tab

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, automation, selenium-chromedriver

**Chrome Browser open up with a new Tab asking for  Window defender wants to reset your setting"**
[image]

**Please help me to resolve this issue**
**This is happening in chrome v.57 and chromeDriver 2.29 ,please let me know if any suggestion**

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 solutions to this:

**Option A**

Create a new browser profile. Restart your machine.

**Option B**

If option A does not solve the issue, then this problem is caused by a key in the registry with the name, `TriggeredReset`. Delete this key, but first to be safe create a system restore point.

1. Click on Start, then on Run. (Win + R)
2. Type in `regedit` and hit return key or click OK.
3. From the menu, select Edit > Find.
4. Select only `Keys` checkbox and enter `TriggeredReset`.
5. It should be located in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome`.
6. Delete the key and close `regedit`.

Try it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: How do I do option A?  Regular chrome opens differently from the automated one.  How do I open the automated one to do this?

Comment: Zeeshan Siddiqui , it will be helpful if you differentiate what are all keys among those Triggered reset

Answer (score 0):

Resetting Windows Defender and deleting TriggeredReset allowed me to open Edge
Version 114.0.1823.67 (Official build) (64-bit) once without getting the error message. I will try making a new profile.