# Chrome settings page opens as default in selenium test

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, selenium

I am a beginner in test automation, Trying to learn selenium.

I did some automation with selenium Chrome Webdriver in C#

i am facing a problem, on execution test, settings page is opening as default in chrome browser, and URL is opening in the 2nd tab.

**Only required URL should open in chrome.......**

i am using selenium chrome driver in c# on windows 10.

can anyone help? how to prevent this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: Have you tried IWebDriver Navigate().GoToUrl() ? Or are you wanting to configure the Chrome web driver options?

Comment: No I did not use this command, i am using the following,  IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver

            

            {
                Url = "http://www.hotmail.com/"
            };

Comment: i tested  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(), result is still the same .- :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
                options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
                driver= new ChromeDriver("path to chrome driver"), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I tried this code but the result is still the same "settings" page is opening as default.

Comment: are you using the latest chrome and chromedriver versions? I also found this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258870/selenium-chrome-webdriver-is-opening-setting-as-default-tab-asking-to-reset-the . I would check that out.

Comment: Chrome Browser 62.0, Slenium-dotnet 3.7.0, Slenium-Java 3.7.1, Chromedriver 2.33, I also tried with Slenium-dotnet 2.53.0, Slenium-Java 2.53.o. someone suggested me.

Comment: problem is fixed with "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961793/window-defender-wants-to-reset-your-setting-chromedriver-2-29-issuechromebrow"